# Does Google TV allow programmatic access to subtitles from the live video source?

Tags: google-tv

Specifically, I want my app to access the subtitles (or other timed text stream) coming in on live TV, whether it be via cable or over the air.  Is this even possible?  If not, is it on the roadmap for a future release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. You could file a feature request at:
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll file that feature request.